# Regex match prefix to suffix without either inbetween

Tags: regex

If my prefix is `<` and my suffix is `>`, then I would want to match only the bolded parts of this string:

.<.**<.>**.>.<.**<.>**.>.

Since the affixes are single characters, this regular expression would work: `<[^<]*?>`

The problem is when the affixes are more than one character. How would I match the bolded parts of this string, where the dots represent any number of unknown characters?

.prefix.**prefix.suffix**.suffix.prefix.**prefix.suffix**.suffix.

**Edit:**
For clarity, it should also match the bolded parts below:

00000000**prefix00000000000000suffix**0000000000

00000000prefix0000**prefix0000suffix**0000000000

00000000**prefix0000suffix**0000suffix0000000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with negative lookaround:

```
prefix((?!prefix).)*?suffix
```

Comment: That only works if you *always* have doubled delimiters. See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/TgIRyTg0ny) showing it not matching `"foo"` in `".prefix.foo.suffix."`

Comment: @Bohemian Your demo appears to match `prefix.foo.suffix`, which is the desired behavior.